# nested HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: windows, windows-registry

One of my programs failed to communicated with another program and I believe the problem is due to nested HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Inside my registry I have the following entries:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT...
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...

I would add that the program defined under the nested entries works properly.
Is this a legit entry?
If not how can i remedy this?

Thank you,

Comment: I don't have them. But why would you consider this to be the issue? What programs failed to communicate and what was the error? What do you mean by defined program under those entries and why don't you just edit your initial post with the updated paths?

Comment: The program which is defined under those nested registry keys is photoshop and the program which failed to communicate with it is an addon of photoshop.
I guess this addon is searching under specific registration keys for photoshop definition.
It must be looking under HKCR\Photoshop.Application.100 .
On my PC this regkey is under: 
HKCR\HKCR\Photoshop.Application.100 (nested HKCR)
I have another PC and in that one I do not have any nested HKCR and photoshop is under HKCR\Photoshop.Application.100 (not nested).

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Photoshop? You could just export the key and reimport it into the registry. It might break all the things though. Still, what was the actual error?

Comment: it was:
"Cannot communicate with Photoshop"

Comment: if i export a value and then import it, won't it be imported to the same location?

Comment: You will have to edit the export. It's a simple text file even if it's named `.reg`. Just search and replace the offending part of the paths. It's an easy format.

Comment: thanks, i uninstalled and reinstalled photoshop and it solved this.